# Material Design Elevation - How to do it on a solid black background

Tags: android, material-design

If I want to incorporate Material Design's Elevation using shadows in black-background GUI, is it possible?  I don't see much written about this in the Android website.  Does black background totally kills the Elevation concept?

Answer (score 3):

Material design isn't designed to have a completely black background as you won't have a a paper with the color `#000000`, so you won't get a very good result.

And with a black background you can't gat a even darker color for the Action Bar and the Notification Bar, as it is supposed in Material design.

If you want a dark Theme consider using a dark grey, for example `#121212` like the example from the [Material design spec](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#properties).